# How to make this code in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make or copy the code that is used to connect the drop list as in this web page please. I talk about when I select one of the options I get other options depending on the one I have selected

https://www.correos.go.cr/nosotros/codigopostal/busqueda.html

Comment: if you just want to look at the source code for this page, you can right click anywhere on the page and select "view page source", or more specifically right click on the dropdown you are interested in and select "inspect element". otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean by "make or copy the code"

Comment: You missed something vital, here at SO we do not write, or copy, code, we help with written code. Please read [ask]

Answer (score -1):

Install it from NPM and go through the documentation, hope that it will help you
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-lang-js

```
<script src="js/jquery-lang.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add the following to your HTML page in either the head or body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create language switcher instance
    var lang = new Lang();

    lang.init({
        defaultLang: 'en'
    });
</script>
```

The init() method takes an options object with the following structure:

```
lang.init({
    /**
     * The default language of the page / app.
     * @type String
     * @required 
     */
    defaultLang: 'en',

    /**
     * The current language to set the page to.
     * @type String
     * @optional 
     */
    currentLang: 'en',

    /**
     * This object is only required if you want to override the default
     * settings for cookies.
     */
    cookie: {
        /**
         * Overrides the default cookie name to something else. The default
         * is "langCookie".
         * @type String
         * @optional
         */
        name: 'langCookie',

        expiry: 365,
        path: '/'
    },

    /**
     * If true, cookies will override the "currentLang" option if the
     * cookie is set. You usually shouldn't need to specify this option
     * at all unless your JavaScript lang.init() method is being
     * dynamically generated by PHP or other server-side processor.
     * @type Boolean
     * @optional 
     */
    allowCookieOverride: true
});
```